# How to pass particular dictionary from array of dictionaries in tableview didselect row?

Tags: ios, swift, model

I am having an array of dictionaries, I load that data into `UITableView`.

I want to send the particular dictionary of data to next view controller in did select row method. I write the following code but gives an error  [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsOgp.png).

Once find my following code.

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = mytableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddresBookCell")as! AddresBookCell
                if let value = self.alladdress, value.count > 0{

                cell.editbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateAddress(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                cell.editbutton.tag = indexPath.row

                return cell
            }
        }

 @objc func updateAddress(sender:UIButton)
    {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewAddress")as! NewAddress
        vc.titlename = "Update Address"
        vc.alladdresses = self.alladdress[sender.tag]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: show your didselect row? code and what the error you faced

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'Alladd' to type '[Alladd]?'

Comment: how do you created the `vc.alladdresses`

Comment: That is same as the Source class array

Answer (score 1):

As the error image you send, if I correctly, I think you try to set item Alladd to list [Alladd] in SecondVC. 
Try replace this code:

```
vc.alladdresses = self.alladdress[sender.tag]
```

to this:

```
vc.alladdresses = [self.alladdress[sender.tag]]
```

Let me know if I correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In SecondVC you should declare property, that will store passed dictionary.

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    var dict = NSDictionary()

}
```

In FirstVC you should do:

```
 @objc func updateAddress(sender:UIButton)
    {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewAddress")as! NewAddress
        vc.titlename = "Update Address"
        vc.dict = self.alladdress[sender.tag]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'Alladd' to type 'NSDictionary'